# Root question help needed

Tags: roots

$$\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3+x}}}=x$$

Question is: How to find x?

Could you help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Plug in $x=\frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{13})$ and see what happens.

Comment: You should try to find the solution without Wolfram|Alpha

Comment: Yep, so that's what i need, could you help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this sly trick out. Just keep plugging in for $x$.

$$\begin{align*}
x&=\sqrt{3+x}\\
&=\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3+x}}\\
&=\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3+x}}}\\
&=\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3+\cdots}}}
\end{align*}$$

This recursive behavior implies that

$$\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3+x}}}=\sqrt{3+x}$$

So just cut yourself some slack and solve the equation

$$x=\sqrt{3+x}$$

Comment: How can you exclude other solutions?

Comment: The lack of $\pm$ in the square roots allows us to neglect it. For example, $x^2=4$ has two solutions, whereas $x=\sqrt{2}$ has one. $(x^2-3)^2=x$ has four solutions, $x^2-3=\sqrt{x}\rightarrow x^2=3+\sqrt{x}$ has two solutions, and $x=\sqrt{3+\sqrt{x}}$ has one solution.

Comment: The extra solutions from taking the square root of a square come from the essential $\pm$.